# Not all &nbsp;s are being replaced converting text from a table cell to a textarea

Tags: javascript, regex, string, text, replace

I need your help again,

It seems that not all ;nbsp's are caught and converted into a proper text space. Why would the replace function catch some of the ;nbsp's and not catch and convert the others.

I've attached a pic of the problem.
[image]

Here's a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n6vwrt2v/

I'm beyond puzzled at this one.

the code in question:

```
var y = document.getElementById("table1").children[0].children[0].innerHTML

//some processing first to replace the <br>'s before the final output

y = y.replace(/\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*/g, '\n')

y = y.replace('&nbsp;',' ')
```

Comment: `y = y.replace(/&nbsp;/,' ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looping through the string and replacing until none are left. Replace will only replace first in string. Example:

```
while(y.indexOf("&nbsp;") != -1)
{
   y.replace("&nbsp;", " ");
}
```

Comment: I tried it but your loop just freezes up and nothing happens.